# Can I make a conditional for determinate with table I will inner join with?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 3 tables in my database when I make a consult in table 1 I need to check 1 column if the value is 1 or 2, if 1 I need to do an inner join with table 2 else if the column is 2 I need to do an inner join with table 3. Can I do this all in one sql query?

table 1
id
type-check (1 or 2)

if - table 1.type-check = 1 inner join table 2

else  - table 1.type-check = 2 inner join table 3

thanks, and forgive me for my bad english I'm from Brazil, and still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `inner join`.  But you can construct a query with `left outer join`:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.col1, t3.col1) as col1
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.type_check = 1 and t1.col = t2.col left join
     t3
     on t1.type_check = 2 and t1.col = t3.col;
```

Note that you also need to select the columns from the right table in the `SELECT` clause.